# Dealing with CRF++ and Java in Windows

Tags: java, windows

I try to run CRF++  version 0.64 in Windows by java program "test.java" given by the author. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/crfpp/files/crfpp-win32/0.46/
However, it get stuck at the line

```
   Tagger tagger = new Tagger("-m ../model -v 3 -n2");
```

Maybe I don't know how to install the library CRFPP in Windows. Can anyone help me to run it?

Comment: Isn't the current version 0.58 as of April 2013?  How did you get 0.64?

Answer (score 0):

What error did you get?  One likely problem is that it wasn't built, or failed to build. CRF++ uses JNI to link the java API to the underlying c++ code.